# Googlebot cannot access my WordPress robots.txt

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, robots.txt, google-search-console, googlebot

I have some troubles with Google indexing on my WordPress site.
When I added my site to Google webmaster the `.htaccess` was the following

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Now, I tried to add these lines to `.htaccess` file, but Google still does not index my site.

```
# BOT SETTINGS
SetEnvIfNoCase User-Agent .*google.* search_robot
SetEnvIfNoCase User-Agent .*yahoo.* search_robot
SetEnvIfNoCase User-Agent .*bot.* search_robot
SetEnvIfNoCase User-Agent .*ask.* search_robot

Order Deny,Allow
#Deny from All
Allow from env=search_robot
```

Where am I doing wrong?

Comment: please try to remove **SetEnvIfNoCase User-Agent .*google.* search_robot** part then resubmit it.

Comment: I was a firewall problem. Thank you all

Answer (score 1):

Create **robots.txt** file and upload your wordpress root folder with following code.

```
User-agent: google
Disallow:

User-agent: yahoo
Disallow:

User-agent: bot
Disallow:

User-agent: ask
Disallow:

User-agent: *
Disallow: /
```

And try to remove `#BOT SETTING` in your `.htaccess`.

Comment: I made these changes but google still does not access the robots.txt. If I check robots availability, the test ends with success. But the robots-testing-tools is has an empty robots